# Is there a way to get the opposite value of current boolean without having to implement checks in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

Instead of checking the boolean value, and setting it to the opposite accordingly..- is there a way to set it to 'the opposite value' without having `If` checks?

Something like.. `x = x.OppositeValue`

Comment: Try `x = Not x`

Comment: @ShaiRado Yep, that works hahaha!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Shai Rado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6344363/shai-rado) answered in the comments..

It's `x = Not x`.